# Android creating dashboard with custom widgets

Tags: android, user-interface

I am trying to build user dashboard which will have multiple widgets ( 2 for now ), which will be containing list views inside them quite similar to this image

[image]

I download google io source code but having hard time understanding that, can anyone guide me the right way what i need to do in order to achieve result like or similar to it, so far in know how to create dynamic list views.

What i have thought so far is to create multiple linear layouts next to each other and then add list views to them.